# Android 4.3 BluetoothAdapter cache

Tags: android, caching, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have an app that uses **Bluetooth Low Energy**. Everything works fine I can connect to the my device read/write characteristics etc.

The advertisement data more precisely the **device name** changes based on what mode the user has started.
Let's say the device has 4 different function (modes). For each mode it changes it's name so my application will know what function the user started.

#### The problem

is that `BluetoothAdapter` **caches** the device name so when I call the `getName()` method it will return the name *it cached the first time the adapter discovered the device*.

**Is there a way to clear the `BluetoothAdapter`'s cache other than restarting the whole adapter?**

I have looked in the documentation but couldn't find anything only a confirmation of the cache existing:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getName%28%29

Comment: Your best bet my be trying to look at the source.  Do you know if changing names is a legal thing to do BTLE spec wise?  If so you should file a bug at least.  If not then you need some other methodology for detecting the mode.

Answer (score 3):

Using the device name is a bit hackish. It's not really what the name field is supposed to be used for. However, like @Ifor said: You could file a bug on the cache. I would think that is should get updated.

However there is a number of other data types you can put in the advertisement data. The [GAP section](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile) of the Bluetooth Assigned numbers have the complete list. I would suggest using «Complete List of 16-bit Service Class UUIDs» (if you have standard services with a 16-bit UUID) or «Complete List of 128-bit Service Class UUIDs» (if you are creating your own custom services